# resource is not found on the build path

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, path

I see "The resource is not on the build path of a Java project" a lot when I try to perform java-related features in Eclipse for this source code I imported from an IntelliJ project. eg F3, Ctrl+Shift+O, etc.

This problem doesn't let me see compile errors before building code. Also, it doesn't recognize classes from the import statements.

Tried: right click on the source folder > Build Path > Use as Source Folder.

Tried: project-clean and refreshes.

Tried: modifying .project file to include different  and  in

It ends up adding a lot of red errors to Eclipse and more files to the workspace, altering my original workspace files.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, you are trying to use external jar libraries in your project but eclipse doesn't see them?

Answer (score -1):

You have to configure a couple of things:

your JRE System Lib (your JAVA_HOME)
Add external jar dependencies to the Librairy tab in Configure Build Path.
Add project reference if you have multiple project/module

Without seeing what your workspace look like!!! it's hard to tell what is the problem!

That is why i always use Maven now, since all this is taken care automatically.